# Writing to custom log aswell as laravel.log in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

Im trying to write a custom log for my laravel application, as the application is quite large so I want to organise my log files.

The issue is, if at any point the application errors, it writes to the `laravel.log` file and kills the script, as php does.

So for example, I have a custom log library like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries\Logs;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

use Log;

class CustomLogsLibrary {

    public function userError($error){

        $orderLog = new Logger('users');
        $orderLog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/users.log')), Logger::INFO);
        $orderLog->info('Error 1', $error);

    }

}
```

and then if this is my script

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->nae = $request->name; //Name spelt wrong on purpose
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    if(!$user->save()){
        $errorCode = (new CustomLogsLibrary)->userError($user->save()); 
    }
```

As you can probably see i've spelt 'name' wrong in the user object to force an error.

Laravel then errors on the misspelt name and dies, meaning it never actually reaches my custom log function, instead it logs

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nme' in 'field list'

to `laravel.log` and then dies. I know it will hit the function if the `false` is returned, but when false is not returned and the function errors for a different reason, I still want to log it in a custom file.

How do I get around this?

I want to be able to organise all errors into separate files, and prioritise  writing to those files over the standard `laravel.log` file.

Comment: use `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` render method and add your custom log there

Comment: @rkj Sorry, can you emphasise on what you mean?

Comment: i mean you can use your custom log in Exception handler render method and the path is `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` there you can use condition and custom log based on that condition

Comment: @rkj Could you possibly provide an example if you have a moment? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your custom logger in the `render()` method of Laravel's `Handler` Class located here: `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
   $error = (new CustomLogsLibrary)->userError($exception->getMessage());
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I do have 2 suggestions though:

1. Make your custom log method static so you can call it without having to instantiate a new object every time; there is no reason in this instance for that particular method to not be static as it does not depend on any other variables/methods of the class and is completely stand-alone. The usage would be something like this: `CustomLogsLibrary::userError('Error message')`
2. Instead of letting your application fail out like that, I **HIGHLY** recommend you wrap your code in a try-catch block. You will have more control over the failure case inside of a try-catch, and you can control the user experience a lot better instead of just sending them to an ugly error page.